# Как проверить, что первая буква заглавная? Регулярные выражения в Python django

Tags: python, django, регулярные-выражения, re

**forms**

```
class SettingServiceAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['name']

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if re.match(r'\w', name):
            raise ValidationError('Название не должно начинаться с маленькой буквы')
        return name
```

как сделать регулярное выражение, чтобы название не начиналось с маленькой буквы буквы?

Comment: А зачем здесь регулярное выражение? `name[0].isupper()`

Comment: да, тоже способ, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы название не начиналось с маленькой буквы, используйте следующую проверку:

```py
if name[0].islower():
    raise ValidationError('Название не должно начинаться с маленькой буквы')
```

Если по какой-то причине вам нужно найти маленькую букву с помощью именно регулярного выражения, вы можете использовать `[a-zа-яё]`.

Если требуется поддержка всех маленьких букв в разных языках, установите модуль [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) и используйте `\p{Ll}` или `[[:lower:]]`. Заглавные буквы можно найти с помощью `\p{Lu}` или `[[:upper:]]`. Если установить `regex` не входит в ваши планы, можно создать подобный шаблон и с помощью `re`:

```
import sys
lowers = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]))
uppers = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).isupper()]))
```

Переменные `lowers` и `uppers` можно затем использовать для создания разных регулярных выражений, например, для нахождения всех слов, начинающихся с заглавной или маленькой буквы, `re.findall(fr'\b{uppers}[^\W\d_]*\b', text)` или `re.findall(fr'\b{lowers}[^\W\d_]*\b', text)`.